# Put the title of the first post in the subject of a MailChimp RSS campaign

Tags: email, rss, mailchimp

I'm using MailChimp and RSS to send emails from my blog. I would like to use the first post title as the subject of the RSS email. When I try to do this, I get the following error:

> Message Subject*
>   De InterMission Uitdaging van vandaag: `*|RSSITEMS:|**|RSSITEM:URL|**|END:RSSITEMS|*`
>   This field can not contain conditional merge tags

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Wait, mailchimp and that sort of stuff is considered on-topic at StackOverflow?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ah, got it: `*|RSSITEM:TITLE|*` is actually sufficient.

Got it confirmed by the MailChimp people: https://longrep.ly/r/5e1ddb41.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer if it's the one to solve the issue

Comment: The longrep.ly link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that doesn't work in a perfect way. It will prepends a "[test]" to your email subject. And according to mailChimp's helpdesk, this tag is not officially allowed to put in the subject. Only valid tags are:
http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/merge-tag-cheatsheet-for-subject-lines/

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for the answer. It seems that they now support the `*|RSSITEM:TITLE|*` as well. Check the long reply of MailChimp in my answer.